# Symfony API Platform entity inheritance

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

My project uses doctrine2 Class Table Inheritance on entities and API Platform to provide API endpoint.

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PartyRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "org" = "Organization",
 *      "person" = "Person"
 * })
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
abstract class Party {}

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PersonRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "person" = "Person",
 *      "agent" = "Agent"
 * })
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Person extends Party {}

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AgentRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Agent extends Person {
    private $affiliation;
}
```

The problem is when looking at API platform model for `Person` it has all children properties like `Agent::$affiliation`.

```
Agent {
  affiliation string
  name string
    readOnly: true

  familyName string
  givenName string
  id string
    readOnly: true

  createdAt string($date-time)
  updatedAt string($date-time)
}

Person {
  name string
    readOnly: true

  familyName string
  givenName string
  id string
    readOnly: true

  createdAt string($date-time)
  updatedAt string($date-time)
  affiliation string
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the [docs for doctrine Class Table Inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) under "Things to note":

> The @InheritanceType, @DiscriminatorColumn and @DiscriminatorMap must be specified on the **topmost** class that is part of the mapped entity hierarchy

Try the following, and update the schema

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PartyRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "org" = "Organization",
 *      "person" = "Person",
 *      "agent" = "Agent"
 * })
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
abstract class Party {}

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PersonRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Person extends Party {}

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AgentRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Agent extends Person {
    private $affiliation;
}
```

Comment: Tried that already it's the same. BTW both ways work for everything else so I ended up separating Person/Org as it makes more sense to me... but now I think maybe it's safer to revert to the "doc" way.